# I'm in need of a little bit of relation, but I'm not sure how to do it

Tags: mongodb

I've been using MongoDB for a bit and I love it. Like most I migrated from using SQL. I have not had any problems with the database or the performance that it gives and I can say that over-all I extremely love the flexibility.

However, I've ran into an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve (correctly) using Mongo.

I've gone through and added friends and messaging to my application, which as you can imagine requires some relation. There's a few points here that I don't understand:

- Pending friend requests
- Mapping messages between two friends.

Putting all of this in the accounts document seems like it'd be ridiculous, I just don't have the slightest clue how to go about it.

I know that once a friend request is completed, I can add a pointer into an array for friends, IE:

```
friends: [pointer(document), pointer(documnet)]
```

Would doing this for all requests be sufficient though...?

How would User B know that User A sent him a request.
How would User A know that they already sent user B a request.

Any material on displaying these kind of relations in Mongo would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about link collections like `pending_friendships: [user, to_be_friend_user]`. Each document representing the user, the user who the current user wants to be friend with and some meta data.

Comment: @AliDehghani So you're recommending a separate collection that contains documents containing all of the pending data, and the main document points to the pending documents? I really can't grasp how this would look.

Comment: Collection of `{"user_id": "some id", "to_be_friend_id": "some id", ...}`

Comment: Wouldn't you have to store this data on both accounts? Seems like the document would get extremely large very quickly.

Comment: Every time you want to collect a user's friend requests, just `group by` `to_be_friend_id`.

Comment: You would have one document for each friend request..Yes it would be very large.. The other and a bit de-normalized approach is to save sent and received friend requests in each user document, as you did for actual friendships

Comment: Actually the de-normalized approach is better than first one